# Tab Bar Height and button size - Fixed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

i have a custom tab bar controller, that i want to add 2 buttons to.  1 enlarged centre button and 1 button on the left to create a side out burger menu that is launched from the tab bar instead instead of the top navigation bar.

i was going to try and get the tab bar height programatically so i can set the button heights ect from that.  so i read up and tried the following code which does not work.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

i read somewhere else that the tabbar is always a fixed 49 pixels regardless of device?

if that is the case is it safe to use something like:

```
menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - (CGFloat(49) - menuButtonFrame.size.height) / 2
```

to set the position of my button? (the black box) its not positions right just yet

also wondering what the default value for the tabbar button is?

[image]

Comment: can you share you screen ?

Comment: i have added screenshot to question.  the button is not positioned correctly yet just mainly wondering about height of tab bar, is it static and the button size by default?

Comment: not sure about your requirement but hope this link can help you. https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

Comment: you have to use a custom tabbar

Comment: Maybe this article I just found might help you https://equaleyes.com/blog/2017/09/04/the-common-raised-center-button-problems-in-tabbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIView Like this and set the height of the center item as your wish.

[image]

And then in TabbarView Controller. add this view to the tabbar View Like this.

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

        customNavBar = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomTabBarView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        bdNavBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.tabBar.addSubview(customNavBar)
```

And then add Constraints to the custom Tabbar.

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customNavBar, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant:  0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customNavBar, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant:  0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customNavBar, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant:  0))
bdNavBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customNavBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:  50))        
self.tabBar.bringSubviewToFront(customNavBar)
```